# Android Espresso testing SwipeRefreshLayout OnRefresh not been triggered on swipeDown

Tags: android, integration-testing, android-espresso, robolectric, swiperefreshlayout

I'm trying to write simple test for pull to refresh as a part of integration testing. I'm using the newest androidX testing components and Robolectric. I'm testing isolated fragment in which one I'm injecting mocked presenter.

XML layout part

```
<androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/refreshLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerTasks"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"/>
</androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Fragment part

```
binding.refreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                presenter.onRefresh();
            }
        });
```

Test:

```
onView(withId(R.id.refreshLayout)).perform(swipeDown());
verify(presenter).onRefresh();
```

but test doesn't pass, message:

> Wanted but not invoked: presenter.onRefresh();

The app works perfectly fine and pull to refresh calls presenter.onRefresh(). I did also debugging of the test and setOnRefreshListener been called and it's not a null. If I do testing with custom matcher to check the status of SwipeRefreshLayout test passes.

```
onView(withId(R.id.refreshLayout)).check(matches(isRefreshing()));
```

Answer (score 5):

I did some minor investigation over last weekend since I was facing the same issue and it was bothering me. I also did some comparing with what happens on a device to spot the differences.

Internally `androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout` has an `mRefreshListener` that will run when `onAnimationEnd` is called. The `AnimationEnd` will trigger then `OnRefreshListener.onRefresh` method.

That animation listener (`mRefreshListener`) is passed to the `mCircleView (CircleImageView)` and the circle animation start is called.

On a device when the view `draw` method is called it will call the `applyLegacyAnimation` method that will, in turn, call the `AnimationStart` method. At the `AnimationEnd,` the `onRefresh` method will be called.

On Robolectric the draw method of the `View` is never called since the items are not actually drawn. This means that the animation will never run and thus neither will the `onRefresh` method.

My conclusion is that with the current version of Robolectric is not possible to verify that the `onRefresh` called due to implementation limitations. It seems though that it is planned to have a realistic rendering in the future.

Comment: Thanks for detail explanation. I agree with you, I did pretty much the same investigation. In Espresso on real device the test passes.

Answer (score 2):

I'm finally able to solve this using a hacky way :

```
fun swipeToRefresh(): ViewAction {
    return object : ViewAction {
        override fun getConstraints(): Matcher<View>? {
            return object : BaseMatcher<View>() {
                override fun matches(item: Any): Boolean {
                    return isA(SwipeRefreshLayout::class.java).matches(item)
                }
                override fun describeMismatch(item: Any, mismatchDescription: Description) {
                    mismatchDescription.appendText(
                        "Expected SwipeRefreshLayout or its Descendant, but got other View"
                    )
                }
                override fun describeTo(description: Description) {
                    description.appendText(
                        "Action SwipeToRefresh to view SwipeRefreshLayout or its descendant"
                    )
                }
            }
        }

        override fun getDescription(): String {
            return "Perform swipeToRefresh on the SwipeRefreshLayout"
        }

        override fun perform(uiController: UiController, view: View) {
            val swipeRefreshLayout = view as SwipeRefreshLayout
            swipeRefreshLayout.run {
                isRefreshing = true
                // set mNotify to true
                val notify = SwipeRefreshLayout::class.memberProperties.find {
                    it.name == "mNotify"
                }
                notify?.isAccessible = true
                if (notify is KMutableProperty<*>) {
                    notify.setter.call(this, true)
                }
                // mockk mRefreshListener onAnimationEnd
                val refreshListener = SwipeRefreshLayout::class.memberProperties.find {
                    it.name == "mRefreshListener"
                }
                refreshListener?.isAccessible = true
                val animatorListener = refreshListener?.get(this) as Animation.AnimationListener
                animatorListener.onAnimationEnd(mockk())
            }
        }
    }
}
```